# Retrieve json elements using for loop gives undefied in jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON from Java that looks like this:

```
[{
    "col_name_1": "Name",
    "col_value_1": "Deepu",
    "col_name_2": "Age",
    "col_value_2": "22",
    "col_name_3": "gender",
    "col_value_3": "Male"
}]
```

Some times the number of content (key value pair) of JSON may increase or decrease. So I decided to retrieve the data using `for loop` in jQuery. My code is:

```
var tabdata = $.parseJSON(data);
var ele_count = Object.keys(tabdata[0]).length; 
ele_count = parseInt(ele_count) / 2;  //total key-value pair

for (var j = 1; j <= parseInt(ele_count); j++) {
    var cn = "col_name_" + j;
    var cv = "col_value_" + j;
    alert(tabdata[0].cn);
    alert(tabdata[0].cv);
}
```

Both alerts give `undefined`. But using 
`tabdata[0].col_name_1` or `tabdata[0].col_value_1` etc gives the desired result. The problem is inside the `for` loop. Can someone help me?

Comment: the ugliest json i ever seen

Comment: @madalinivascu, its created using for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code [`.cn` will try to get property `cn`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Dot_notation) of the object which is `undefined`. So instead use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) to access object property with help of variable.

```
alert(tabdata[0][cn]);
alert(tabdata[0][cv]);
```

Comment: @next2u : glad to help u :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use bracket notation when accessing the property of an object through a variable. Try this:

```
for (var j = 1; j <= parseInt(ele_count); j++) {
    var cn = "col_name_" + j;
    var cv = "col_value_" + j;
    console.log(tabdata[0][cn]);
    console.log(tabdata[0][cv]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is working example: https://jsfiddle.net/y4x93mdq/

```
alert(tabdata[0][cn]);
alert(tabdata[0][cv]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try the jquery `each` function

```
    var obj = [{"col_name_1":"Name","col_value_1":"Deepu","col_name_2":"Age","col_value_2":"22","col_name_3":"gender","col_value_3":"Male"}] ;

$.each(obj[0],function(i,v){
console.log(v);
});
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ppyzb41r/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following inside your for loop

```js
tabdata[0][cn]
```